# Card.io sdk in android phonegap, does not get any other data except Credit card number

Tags: card.io

I am working with the card.io Android PhoneGap SDK but have had trouble with getting any other data except credit card number. I also want to get the name and expiry date. Is there a way to do that in the latest card.io sdk?

In CardIOPGPlugin.js (https://github.com/mudasserajaz12/card.io-phonegap-plugin/blob/b5cb05d502b84e5b4d1bd029ebc7ec81e3134345/www/card.io.js), it is written in the comments that:

//Your response array contain these fields
// redacted_card_number, card_number, expiry_month,expiry_year, cvv, zip

Is there anything which i am missing? please guide me, thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Dave from card.io here.

card.io is designed to automatically scan the card number. We are currently working on also scanning the expiration date.

Besides using automatic scanning, the user can also choose to tap the "Enter Manually" button, in which case card number, expiration date, CVV, and ZIP are all available. This is the route through which the various other fields in the response array will be filled in.

Comment: I couldn't find a plugin for android which has "Enter Manually button". I tried some 3rd party plugins but they are some how causing the app to crash. Any help?

Comment: A very helpful developer from [Keepe](http://www.keepe.com/) has created a PhoneGap plug-in with Android support; it can be found [here in the Corodova Plugin Registry](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.keepe.cardio). I suggest that you try that plug-in, and contact its creator if you run into problems.

Comment: I have been using card.io phonegap plugin, it looks great. Just wonder where does card image is located after scanning?